# How to test a claim that 95% of passengers are processed in 40 minutes or less

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I need to test a claim made by a company stating that 95% of the cases (passangers per day, peak hour) are processed in 40 minutes or less.

1. I assume I must collect a passanger sample but how many cases (I was thinking about 60, N is around 15.000)?
2. What is the best technique to test the claim? Can bootstrap be used?
3. Any advice or references are welcome.

Edit: This is for an audit and, in case of fraud, there are penaties involved. More recently, company claims 100% of the passangers are processed below that mark and that is what raised the doubt. We are convinced this is unlikely and some trick is being used, therefore the audit.

Comment: As a matter of terminology, this claim is a statement about a *proportion* of a population. It can be thought of as a confidence *limit* for the 95th percentile of a population (usually known as a *tolerance limit*). It is a matter of conjecture whether the company intends it as a *lower* tolerance limit--in which case it is not confident that 95% of all cases truly are processed in 40 minutes or less, but this is possible--or an *upper* tolerance limit, in which case the company is quite confident of its claim. This has a strong bearing on how large a sample is needed to test the claim.

Comment: In addition to whuber's comments: It sounds like you're going to gather some data at a single location in a single day, which is arguably not what they're talking about. If not, how are you going to gather your sample in a way that reflects their N?

Comment: @ Wayne. They state that in that particular location, 95% of their passagers are handled in <40 mim mark. I guess my sample collection (I still have to find the adequate size) has to be gathered on that site on a regular day.